# Why does my batch password encoder not work?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am making a batch file encoder. The user inputs their password character by character and then the output is a simple code for that character. When i run this all i receive is every "true" echoing onto the output. Please help!

```
@echo off

set /p num1=Character1:

set /p num2=Character2:

set /p num3=Character3:

set /p num4=Character4:

set /p num5=Character5:

set /p num6=Character6:



if %num1%==a goto true1
if %num1%==b goto true2
if %num1%==c goto true3
if %num1%==d goto true4
if %num1%==e goto true5
if %num1%==f goto true6
if %num1%==g goto true7
if %num1%==h goto true8
if %num1%==i goto true9
if %num1%==j goto true10
if %num1%==k goto true11
if %num1%==l goto true12
if %num1%==m goto true13
if %num1%==n goto true14
if %num1%==o goto true15
if %num1%==p goto true16
if %num1%==q goto true17
if %num1%==r goto true18
if %num1%==s goto true19
if %num1%==t goto true20
if %num1%==u goto true21
if %num1%==v goto true22
if %num1%==w goto true23
if %num1%==x goto true24
if %num1%==y goto true25
if %num1%==z goto true26


if %num2%==a goto true27
if %num2%==b goto true28
if %num2%==c goto true29
if %num2%==d goto true30
if %num2%==f goto true32
if %num2%==g goto true33
if %num2%==h goto true34
if %num2%==i goto true35
if %num2%==j goto true36
if %num2%==k goto true37
if %num2%==l goto true38
if %num2%==m goto true39
if %num2%==n goto true40
if %num2%==o goto true41
if %num2%==p goto true42
if %num2%==q goto true43
if %num2%==r goto true44
if %num2%==s goto true45
if %num2%==t goto true46
if %num2%==u goto true47
if %num2%==v goto true48
if %num2%==w goto true49
if %num2%==x goto true50
if %num2%==y goto true51
if %num2%==z goto true52


if %num3%==a goto true53
if %num3%==b goto true54
if %num3%==c goto true55
if %num3%==d goto true56
if %num3%==e goto true57
if %num3%==f goto true58
if %num3%==g goto true59
if %num3%==h goto true60
if %num3%==i goto true61
if %num3%==j goto true62
if %num3%==k goto true63
if %num3%==l goto true64
if %num3%==m goto true65
if %num3%==n goto true66
if %num3%==o goto true67
if %num3%==p goto true68
if %num3%==q goto true69
if %num3%==r goto true70
if %num3%==s goto true71
if %num3%==t goto true72
if %num3%==u goto true73
if %num3%==v goto true74
if %num3%==w goto true75
if %num3%==x goto true76
if %num3%==y goto true77
if %num3%==z goto true78


if %num4%==a goto true79
if %num4%==b goto true80
if %num4%==c goto true81
if %num4%==d goto true82
if %num4%==e goto true83
if %num4%==f goto true84
if %num4%==g goto true85
if %num4%==h goto true86
if %num4%==i goto true87
if %num4%==j goto true88
if %num4%==k goto true89
if %num4%==l goto true90
if %num4%==m goto true91
if %num4%==n goto true92
if %num4%==o goto true93
if %num4%==p goto true94
if %num4%==q goto true95
if %num4%==r goto true96
if %num4%==s goto true97
if %num4%==t goto true98
if %num4%==u goto true99
if %num4%==v goto true100
if %num4%==w goto true101
if %num4%==x goto true102
if %num4%==y goto true103
if %num4%==z goto true104


if %num5%==a goto true105
if %num5%==b goto true106
if %num5%==c goto true107
if %num5%==d goto true108
if %num5%==e goto true109
if %num5%==f goto true110
if %num5%==g goto true111
if %num5%==h goto true112
if %num5%==i goto true113
if %num5%==j goto true114
if %num5%==k goto true115
if %num5%==l goto true116
if %num5%==m goto true117
if %num5%==n goto true118
if %num5%==p goto true120
if %num5%==q goto true121
if %num5%==r goto true122
if %num5%==s goto true123
if %num5%==t goto true124
if %num5%==u goto true125
if %num5%==v goto true126
if %num5%==w goto true127
if %num5%==x goto true128
if %num5%==y goto true129
if %num5%==z goto true130

if %num6%==a goto true131
if %num6%==b goto true132
if %num6%==c goto true133
if %num6%==d goto true134
if %num6%==e goto true135
if %num6%==f goto true136
if %num6%==g goto true137
if %num6%==h goto true138
if %num6%==i goto true139
if %num6%==j goto true140
if %num6%==k goto true141
if %num6%==l goto true142
if %num6%==m goto true143
if %num6%==n goto true144
if %num6%==o goto true145
if %num6%==p goto true146
if %num6%==q goto true147
if %num6%==r goto true148
if %num6%==s goto true149
if %num6%==t goto true150
if %num6%==u goto true151
if %num6%==v goto true152
if %num6%==w goto true153
if %num6%==x goto true154
if %num6%==y goto true155
if %num6%==z goto true156


:true1
echo Cipher text- pl
:true2
echo Cipher text- vd
:true3
echo Cipher text- ed
:true4
echo Cipher text- jy
:true5
echo Cipher text- as
:true6
echo Cipher text- kv
:true7
echo Cipher text- 5g
:true8
echo Cipher text- j8
:true9
echo Cipher text- s2
:true10
echo Cipher text- sk
:true11
echo Cipher text- 34
:true12
echo Cipher text- gx
:true13
echo Cipher text- 7h
:true14
echo Cipher text- sr
:true15
echo Cipher text- mb
:true16
echo Cipher text- 6g
:true17
echo Cipher text- 8i
:true18
echo Cipher text- id
:true19
echo Cipher text- 28
:true20
echo Cipher text- s6
:true21
echo Cipher text- 4k
:true22
echo Cipher text- 6h
:true23
echo Cipher text- 3f
:true24
echo Cipher text- jf
:true25
echo Cipher text- 8d
:true26
echo Cipher text- 2s



:true27
echo Cipher text- pl
:true28
echo Cipher text- vd
:true29
echo Cipher text- ed
:true30
echo Cipher text- jy
:true31
echo Cipher text- as
:true32
echo Cipher text- kv
:true33
echo Cipher text- 5g
:true34
echo Cipher text- j8
:true35
echo Cipher text- s2
:true36
echo Cipher text- sk
:true37
echo Cipher text- 34
:true38
echo Cipher text- gx
:true39
echo Cipher text- 7h
:true40
echo Cipher text- sr
:true41
echo Cipher text- mb
:true42
echo Cipher text- 6g
:true43
echo Cipher text- 8i
:true44
echo Cipher text- id
:true45
echo Cipher text- 28
:true46
echo Cipher text- s6
:true47
echo Cipher text- 4k
:true48
echo Cipher text- 6h
:true49
echo Cipher text- 3f
:true50
echo Cipher text- jf
:true51
echo Cipher text- 8d
:true52
echo Cipher text- 2s


:true53
echo Cipher text- pl
:true54
echo Cipher text- vd
:true55
echo Cipher text- ed
 :true56
echo Cipher text- jy
:true57
echo Cipher text- as
:true58
echo Cipher text- kv
:true59
echo Cipher text- 5g
:true60
echo Cipher text- j8
:true61
echo Cipher text- s2
:true62
echo Cipher text- sk
:true63
echo Cipher text- 34
:true64
echo Cipher text- gx
:true65
echo Cipher text- 7h
:true66
echo Cipher text- sr
:true67
echo Cipher text- mb
:true68
echo Cipher text- 6g
:true69
echo Cipher text- 8i
:true70
echo Cipher text- id
:true71
echo Cipher text- 28
:true72
echo Cipher text- s6
:true73
echo Cipher text- 4k
:true74
echo Cipher text- 6h
:true75
echo Cipher text- 3f
:true76
echo Cipher text- jf
:true77
echo Cipher text- 8d
:true78
echo Cipher text- 2s

:true79
echo Cipher text- pl
:true80
echo Cipher text- vd
:true81
 echo Cipher text- ed
:true82
echo Cipher text- jy
:true83
echo Cipher text- as
:true84
echo Cipher text- kv
:true85
echo Cipher text- 5g
:true86
echo Cipher text- j8
:true87
echo Cipher text- s2
:true88
echo Cipher text- sk
:true89
echo Cipher text- 34
:true90
echo Cipher text- gx
:true91
echo Cipher text- 7h
:true92
echo Cipher text- sr
:true93
 echo Cipher text- mb
:true94
 echo Cipher text- 6g
 :true95
 echo Cipher text- 8i
:true96
 echo Cipher text- id
:true97
 echo Cipher text- 28
:true98
echo Cipher text- s6
:true99
echo Cipher text- 4k
:true100
echo Cipher text- 6h
:true101
echo Cipher text- 3f
:true102
echo Cipher text- jf
:true103
echo Cipher text- 8d
:true104
echo Cipher text- 2s


:true105
echo Cipher text- pl
:true106
echo Cipher text- vd
:true107
echo Cipher text- ed
:true108
echo Cipher text- jy
:true109
echo Cipher text- as
:true110
echo Cipher text- kv
:true111
echo Cipher text- 5g
:true112
echo Cipher text- j8
:true113
echo Cipher text- s2
:true114
 echo Cipher text- sk
:true115
 echo Cipher text- 34
:true116
echo Cipher text- gx
:true117
echo Cipher text- 7h
:true118
echo Cipher text- sr
:true119
echo Cipher text- mb
:true120
echo Cipher text- 6g
 :true121
echo Cipher text- 8i
  :true122
  echo Cipher text- id
:true123
echo Cipher text- 28
:true124
echo Cipher text- s6
:true125
echo Cipher text- 4k
:true126
 echo Cipher text- 6h
 :true127
echo Cipher text- 3f
:true128
echo Cipher text- jf
:true129
echo Cipher text- 8d
:true130
echo Cipher text- 2s


:true131
echo Cipher text- pl
:true132
echo Cipher text- vd
:true133
echo Cipher text- ed
:true134
echo Cipher text- jy
:true135
echo Cipher text- as
:true136
echo Cipher text- kv
:true137
echo Cipher text- 5g
 :true138
echo Cipher text- j8
:true139
echo Cipher text- s2
:true140
echo Cipher text- sk
:true141
echo Cipher text- 34
:true142
echo Cipher text- gx
:true143
echo Cipher text- 7h
:true144
echo Cipher text- sr
:true145
echo Cipher text- mb
 :true146
echo Cipher text- 6g
:true147
echo Cipher text- 8i
:true148
echo Cipher text- id
:true149
echo Cipher text- 28
:true150
echo Cipher text- s6
:true151
echo Cipher text- 4k
:true152
echo Cipher text- 6h
:true153
echo Cipher text- 3f
:true154
echo Cipher text- jf
:true155
echo Cipher text- 8d
:true156
echo Cipher text- 2s
pause > nul
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

Batch files don't stop processing at a label, they just move to the next line and keep processing so you program will process the `goto` on the first character that matches %num1%, jump to that label and run to the end of the program.

So in each of your labels you need to add `goto :eof` which will jump to the end of the file.   If you do that you will only process a match for %num1%, because it will jump to the matching label, then to the end of the file which will exit the program.

You can fix this by replacing your `goto`'s on the if statements with `call`.  This will run the code at the label, and when the code jumps to the end of the file it will return to line after the call.

Finally you will need to add a `goto :eof` at the end of your if blocks to keep the batch file from running through each of the label statements.

So something like (to show a small snippet of your code)

```
if %num6%==y call :true155
if %num6%==z call :true156

pause > nul

:true1
echo Cipher text- pl
goto :eof
:true2
echo Cipher text- vd
goto :eof
```

Comment: +1 Note that the `:` is needed for the call commands. `call :true155`  Also you may want to add a `goto :eof` after the `pause` as well to prevent fall through.

Answer (score 2):

Although the other answers stated the immediate problem with your program, I can't resist the temptation to make some observations about it. You should study Batch file features and try to use they in order to write better (simpler, faster) programs. This is true in all programming languages, but particularly in Batch files; otherwise you will write rudimentary and crude programs that certainly are not good examples of what a Batch file can be. For example:

1- You should realize that if you check each one of the six input characters and execute six different sections of code *with the same conversions*, then it is a waste of code! You may write the set of conversions just one time and then use it in six different sections. This concept is called "subroutine".

2- In general, if you write the same section of code many times just changing a small part, then you are not using the capabilities of the programming language to do so. You may write a "general format" of the code and place a "parameter" in the part that must change, and then let the programming language to automatically change that parameter over a range of values. This is a "loop" and the way to achieve it in Batch files is via `FOR` command.

3- One of the most important concepts in programming languages is the *array* that allows you to specify a certain operation on one element, and then repeat that operation over a range of elements in the same way by just changing an *index*. If you combine an array inside a `FOR` loop, you may achieve large and complex calculations in a few lines of code.

Yes, I know that these methods are usually obtained through the experience; however, I just wanted to present them to you so you may realize that they exists. Below there is a Batch file that use these methods to achieve the same result of your original program, but that is much smaller.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in ("a=pl" "b=vd" "c=ed" "d=jy" "e=as" "f=kv" "g=5g" "h=j8" "i=s2" "j=sk" "k=34" "l=gx" "m=7h"
            "n=sr" "o=mb" "p=6g" "q=8i" "r=id" "s=28" "t=s6" "u=4k" "v=6h" "w=3f" "x=jf" "y=8d" "z=2s") do (
   set letter_%%~a
)

rem Read the characters
for /L %%i in (1,1,6) do (
   set /p num%%i=Character%%i: 
)

rem Check the characters
for /L %%i in (1,1,6) do for %%c in (!num%%i!) do (
   if defined letter_%%c echo Cipher text- !letter_%%c!
)

pause > nul
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue

There are no return `goto` statements to go back and continue processing, therefore only the first `goto` will be processed and then fall through everything below.

#### Alternate Example

Here is an example that will do what you are trying but with much less code and error checking:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Dictionary=00,pl,vd,ed,jy,as,kv,5g,j8,s2,sk,34,gx,7h,sr,mb,6g,8i,id,28,s6,4k,6h,3f,jf,8d,2s"
set "Count=1"
:Prompt
set "Input="
set /p "Input=Character%Count%:"
if not defined Input goto Prompt
set "Input=%Input:"=%"
for /f "delims=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" %%A in ("%Input%") do goto :Error
echo %Input%|choice /c abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz /n >nul
set /a "Index=%ErrorLevel% * 3"
echo Cipher text- !Dictionary:~%Index%,2!
set /a "Count+=1"
if %Count% gtr 6 goto Stop
goto Prompt

:Error
echo Invalid Input
goto Prompt

:Stop
pause >nul
endlocal
```

#### Output

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>script.bat
Character1:a
Cipher text- pl
Character2:b
Cipher text- vd
Character3:c
Cipher text- ed
Character4:d
Cipher text- jy
Character5:z
Cipher text- 2s
Character6:a
Cipher text- pl
```

Comment: Actually if he uses `call` he can return with `goto :eof`

Comment: @Monacraft  +1 Yep, that is the probably the best way to structure the script (into routines).